# Recursively group sentences based on conjunctions

Tags: python, regex, string, text, recursion

I have a list of sentences such as:

```
Sentence 1.
And Sentence 2.
Or Sentence 3.
New Sentence 4.
New Sentence 5.
And Sentence 6.
```

I am trying to group these sentences based on "conjunction criteria" such that if next sentence starts with a conjunction (currently just "and" or "or") then I want to group them such that:

```
Group 1:
    Sentence 1.
    And Sentence 2.
    Or Sentence 3.

Group 2:
    New Sentence 4.

Group 3:
    New Sentence 5.
    And Sentence 6.
```

I wrote the following code, it somehow detects the consecutive sentences but not all of them.

How can I recursively code this? I tried to code it iteratively, however there are some cases where it doesn't work and I couldn't figure out how to code this in recursion.

```
tokens = ["Sentence 1.","And Sentence 2.","Or Sentence 3.","New Sentence 4.","New Sentence 5.","And Sentence 6."]
already_selected = []
attachlist = {}
for i in tokens:
    attachlist[i] = []

for i in range(len(tokens)):
    if i in already_selected:
        pass
    else:
        for j in range(i+1, len(tokens)):
            if j not in already_selected:
                first_word = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(tokens[j].lower())[0]
                if first_word in conjucture_list:
                    attachlist[tokens[i]].append(tokens[j])
                    already_selected.append(j)
                else:
                    break
```

Comment: Why do you need it to be recursive? Honestly that's a fool's errand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tokens = ["Sentence 1.","And Sentence 2.","Or Sentence 3.",
          "New Sentence 4.","New Sentence 5.","And Sentence 6."]
result = list()
for token in tokens:
        if not token.startswith("And ") and not token.startswith("Or "): #trailing whitespace because of the cases like "Andy ..." and "Orwell ..."
            result.append([token])
        else:
            result[-1].append(token)
```

Result:

```
[['Sentence 1.', 'And Sentence 2.', 'Or Sentence 3.'],
 ['New Sentence 4.'],
 ['New Sentence 5.', 'And Sentence 6.']]
```

Comment: @unutbu I updated the code based on your idea of encountering cases like "Andy ..." or "Orwell ...". But I don't think it is a good idea to use `result = [tokens[:1]]`or handling IndexError, I'm not interested in malformed texts since there are no directions given in question body for handling such sentences. We may need to catch errors or ignore these sentences altogether , depending on our application.

Answer (score 0):

I have a thing for embedded iterators and generics, so here's a super-generic method:

```
import re

class split_by:
    def __init__(self, iterable, predicate=None):
        self.iter = iter(iterable)
        self.predicate = predicate or bool

        try:
            self.head = next(self.iter)
        except StopIteration:
            self.finished = True
        else:
            self.finished = False

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def _section(self):
        yield self.head

        for self.head in self.iter:
            if self.predicate(self.head):
                break

            yield self.head

        else:
            self.finished = True

    def __next__(self):
        if self.finished:
            raise StopIteration

        section = self._section()
        return section

[list(x) for x in split_by(tokens, lambda sentence: not re.match("(?i)or|and", sentence))]
#>>> [['Sentence 1.', 'And Sentence 2.', 'Or Sentence 3.'], ['New Sentence 4.'], ['New Sentence 5.', 'And Sentence 6.']]
```

It's longer, but it's `O(1)` space complexity and takes a predicate of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved much better iteratively rather than recursively because the output requires only a single level of grouping. If you're looking for a recursive solution, please give an example of arbitrary level grouping.

```
def is_conjunction(sentence):
    return sentence.startswith('And') or sentence.startswith('Or')

tokens = ["Sentence 1.","And Sentence 2.","Or Sentence 3.",
          "New Sentence 4.","New Sentence 5.","And Sentence 6."]
def group_sentences_by_conjunction(sentences):
    result = []
    for s in sentences:
        if result and not is_conjunction(s):
            yield result #flush the last group
            result = []
        result.append(s)
    if result:
        yield result #flush the rest of the result buffer

>>> groups = group_sentences_by_conjunction(tokens)
```

Using a `yield` statement is better when it's possible that your result may not fit in memory, such as reading all sentences from a book stored in a file.
If you need the result as a list for some reason, convert it with

```
>>> groups_list = list(groups)
```

Result:

```
[['Sentence 1.', 'And Sentence 2.', 'Or Sentence 3.'], ['New Sentence 4.'], ['New Sentence 5.', 'And Sentence 6.']]
```

If you need group numbers, use `enumerate(groups)`.

`is_conjunction` will have the same problems as mentioned in other answers. Modify as necessary to meet your criteria.